# How to write to SHPR2 correctly on cortex M0

Tags: arm, cortex-m

What is wrong with this code?
When I debug it in DAVE4 with XMC1100 Boot Kit the SHPR2 register not changing in the debugger. The code is based on EasyMain (LED blinking is working for example with a modified main).

I have studied the DDI0419C_arm_architecture_v6m_reference_manual I think it should work.

```
#include "XMC1100.h"

int main(void)
{
 unsigned int a;

 a = 0x0B << PPB_SHPR2_PRI_11_Pos;
 PPB->SHPR2 |= a;

 while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CMSIS functions should be used.